# Find $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{xy^3}{x+y}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have to compute $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{xy^3}{x+y}$.

When doing polar coordinates, I get $\displaystyle\lim_{r\to0}r^3\frac{\sin^3(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta)}$ but I'm not sure if I can say it's zero because of that denominator.

I also tried this limit through lines, a parabola, and axis, all of them zero.

My professor said something about "what happens whe  $x+y=0$?" And the hint was to take $\displaystyle\frac{xy^3}{x+y}=1$ which implies $\displaystyle x=\frac{y}{y^3-1}$ and we have to check what happens when $y\to0$. However, that leads to $0$. I don't understand what is happening in $\displaystyle x=\frac{y}{y^3-1}$, maybe something related to mean values theorem?

Comment: Try to approach the $(0,0)$ by that curve $x=\frac{y}{y^3-1}$. You have already seen that it crosses $(0,0)$ and it is continuous there.

Comment: Great, thank you very much! I see it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $x = \varepsilon - y$ so that $x + y = \varepsilon$. Then

$$ \frac{xy^3}{x + y} = \frac{(\varepsilon - y) y^3}{\varepsilon} = y^3 - \frac{y^4}{\varepsilon}.$$

So no matter how small $y$ is, we can always choose $\varepsilon$ to make $\frac{y^4}{\varepsilon}$ very very large.

Just make sure that $(\varepsilon - y, y) \to 0$ when you're working out what to choose for $\varepsilon$.

---

But if you want to continue from $$x = \frac{y}{y^3 - 1},$$

then note that $y^3 - 1$ is an increasing function. So if say $|y| < 1/2$ then

$$\left( -\frac12 \right)^3 - 1 < y^3 - 1 < \left( \frac12 \right)^3 - 1.$$

So

$$ -\frac{8}{7} < \frac{1}{y^3 - 1} < -\frac{8}{9}, $$

and therefore $|x| < \frac{8}{7} |y|$.

Really, we're just using the fact that $y^3 - 1 \not\to 0$.